# Short map in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function `penceToPounds :: [Int] -> [Float]` that transforms pences to pounds. I have to solve this using `map`

One long way to do it is:

```
penceToPounds xs = map ptp xs
                   where ptp x = fromIntegral x / 100
```

How do I include fromIntegral if I want to write a shorter version of the function, such as:

```
penceToPounds = map (`div` 100)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write the function in point-free style:

```
penceToPounds = map ( (/ 100) . fromIntegral )
```

or

```
penceToPounds = map $ (/ 100) . fromIntegral
```

Comment: if should be `penceToPounds = map ((/ 100) . fromIntegral)`, because `div` is division for Integral values. Also, `fmap` should be used since it is more general than `map`

Comment: `<$>` is even more general

Comment: @zigazou More general doesn't mean better in all cases. I would use `map` since this function is restricted to work on just lists anyway and when I see `map` I immediately know I only need to worry about lists. Generalization can be good, but if you always make everything as general as possible, things can become very hard to read.

Comment: @VansonSamuel That's exactly as general as `fmap`. It's just a synonym for `fmap` actually.